# How to get hardware sampleRate from iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

In my app I'm using AVAudioEngine for speech recognition, but I'm having hard time understanding how to properly setup inputNode.

I used this tutorial as an example for my code: https://www.raywenderlich.com/155752/speech-recognition-tutorial-ios

This part of the code is giving me headache:

```
let node = audioEngine.inputNode
let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024,
                format: recordingFormat) { [unowned self]
  (buffer, _) in
  self.request.append(buffer)
}

audioEngine.prepare()
try audioEngine.start()
```

Basically, my app crashes with this error:

```
AVAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:897:SetOutputFormat:
(format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate)]
```

So my question is, how do I get hardware sampleRate from the device the app is running on, so I can set it to my recording format for the node?

Also, if the running app is being recorded via mac or being screenshared via apple TV I assume I will need to get the hw sampleRate of those device so my app doesn't crash in those cases too?!

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From AVAudioSession for hardware sample rate.

```
let sampleRate = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate
```

But this might fit your specific case better.

```
let sampleRate = node.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you how to set the sample rate to the hardware sample rate once you have the latter

Comment: node.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate can return smaller rate so your output voice will be small and bad